# Locked question does have an answer

Tags: support, migration

I'm not sure of the proper solution, and I've briefly searched meta. The question [As an intermediate English student, I need ur guidance](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214217/as-an-intermediate-english-student-i-need-ur-guidance) is on hold and locked, but it does have an answer as asked: https://tracktest.eu/english-levels-cefr/ - this is the CEFR, Common European Framework of Reference for Languages.

So... how do I usefully contribute to the Original Poster? I can't edit or comment because it's locked.

Comment: It’s a rejected migration, so it is unlocked on the site it was rejected from, [english.se], although it’s still closed there I believe. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501354/as-an-intermediate-english-student-i-need-ur-guidance

Comment: Aha! The mechanics now make sense. Thank you @ColleenV.

Comment: It's further proof that migrating questions like that, that have no place to be answered on SE, doesn't help anyone, certainly not the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a rejected migration, you will find a banner that says something like this under the question:

> migration rejected from [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/501354/revisions) X hours ago

Unintuitively, the link here sends you back to the revision history on the original site (English Language and Usage). To get to the question itself, you can click on "[Return to Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501354/as-an-intermediate-english-student-i-need-ur-guidance)" at the top of the page. The question on ELU has been unlocked automatically by closing the question on ELL (so you can comment) but it's also still closed (so no answers can be posted) and therefore will be [automatically deleted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) sometime soon.